# Updating Deployed SSIS Package

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ssis

I have a deployed SSIS package, with a schedule and everything. Now, I have made changes to this package. Do I have to re-deploy it, and setup the schedule for it again, or is there a way for an already deployed SSIS package to be updated with the latest build?

Comment: How did You schedule it? Made a job to start at scheduled time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you need to redeploy the package(s) to whatever location the scheduler expects to find the package(s).

You do not, however, need to recreate the job, configurations or any of that jazz, simply perform an in-place replacement of the dtsx package. If you stored it to the file system, copy the new version over it. If you stored it in SQL Server, use the command-line to replace it (approximately dtutil /file PkgName.dtsx /destserver thatdatabase /copy SQL;PkgName) or use the ssismanifest to deploy packages or my current favourite, use [PowerShell for SSIS deployment and maintenance](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/08/powershell-ssis-deployment-and.html)