# Deploy SSIS Package from TFS 2015 Update 2

Tags: sql-server, tfs, ssis, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I have seen some answers to this problem already, but I am in need of a dummies guide to how this is done.

We have a overcome some obstacles already and are now at the point where I am trying to get the resultant package deployed. What I am trying to master is how to create a nuget package so that our Octopus Deploy system can then deploy it to our various platforms.

I have seen this article [PowerShell for SSIS deployment and maintenance](https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/08/powershell-ssis-deployment-and.html) that was inside this article [Updating Deployed SSIS Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7603021/updating-deployed-ssis-package) and is a great script for using PowerShell to deploy, but I need this to be run from TFS as a build step. From this, I am hoping to be able to generate a nuget package.

Is this possible?

Comment: What can nuget/TFS use? Can it run a command line? Can it call `ISDeploymentWizard.exe` to install your package?

Comment: Well I can add a MSBuild step that will take the solution and try and rebuild it. This can then be packaged up as a nuget package

Comment: I checked here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293705.aspx which implies yes you can run command line tools. You need to work out the correct command line to deploy your package then work out the correct syntax to add it as a custom step.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://blogs.adatis.co.uk/jonathon%20eveoconnor/post/Continuous-Integration-With-TeamCity-Automating-SSIS-Build-and-Deployment

Comment: Or this: https://speaksql.wordpress.com/2013/06/07/a-journey-to-db-deployment-automaton-ssis-build-using-msbuild/

Comment: It seems you want to deploy SSIS package in Octopus Deploy system, not  in TFS vNext build, correct? So your query is not TFS related?

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you are trying to create NuGet packages during your TFS build.

To achieve this, you need to add the **NuGet Packager** task. Check this link: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/package/build/team-build